# How to autostart WiFi and an app on (re)boot

Tags: wi-fi, 2.3-gingerbread, auto-start

I would like to have WiFi, and an app (CSipSimple SIP client), start automatically when the phone is (re)booted.

It is running Android 2.3.4, not rooted, and in airplane mode.

Is this possible?

Comment: When in Airplane mode you should be able to enable WiFi and usually this setting should survive reboot. An app has to declare that it wants to start when boot process has completed. There are apps that can start other apps but your system is a bit ancient, it may be a little bit problematic to find such an app version of an app starter that still supports your system.

Comment: @Robert Every time the phone is powered on, the WiFi is always disabled, even if it was enabled when it was powered off. I wondered if there is a setting for this, but haven't found anything. I have also searched for autostart settings for CSipSimple but haven't found one yet. I'm not sure if it exists. It certainly is difficult to find many apps that still support this version of Android.

Comment: I don't remember if the Wifi setting was generally behaving this way in Android 2.3. I once had a 2.3 device but that was years ago.

Comment: Try Automate app. As the name suggests you can automate things JUST AS YOU WANT. Tell me if you're interested, i'll post an answer :)

Comment: @Aayush Good to know about this app, but according to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate it requires Android 4+ and I don't see a way to download it without the Play Store. Are there older versions available supporting Android 2.3 ?

Comment: https://apkpure.com/automate/com.llamalab.automate/download?from=details

Comment: @Aayush The earliest version I see is v1.10.0 which still requires Android 4+.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find a version of Tasker compatible with your phone, it would allow you to start an app on boot.

Edit: The developer makes versions available for older Android releases [here](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/download.html)

Comment: Does Tasker run on unrooted devices? Where can I find a safe/official version which supports Android 2.3.4?

Comment: Yes, it runs on unrooted devices.  Some functionality may not be available, depending on Android version.   Answer updated to link to developer's download page.

Comment: That's great that the developer makes older versions available, though the downloads are for trials which "expire after 7 days unless you purchase the license from Google Play." That's a problem because the phone (Samsung Gio S5660) has only 158MB of internal memory which I'm not sure will even allow upgrading the Android Market to Play Store, plus I'd rather use the device without a Google account.